# How to get a printer to report back to in house application

Tags: printing, protocols, accounting

I want a printer to report back to my in house application the accounting code the user typed in. How do I do that?

Note to mods: mods at serverfault sent me here.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is printer manufacturer specific, and you haven't specified what printing infrastructure you have.

Each manufacturer implements this type of accounting in a different way, and most have changed methods over time.

It could come back via LDAP, an API call, or SOAP web service.

It could be that you have to poll the printers to retrieve their per-user or per-department counters for colour, b&w, stapling etc.

It could be that your solution is influenced by the access control solution you use, like swipe cards, tokens or mobile phone proxmity, as these often have integrated job accounting functionality.

There could also be a central management app, that accumulates the data from many printers, like HP's Access Control Job Accounting.

The solution you choose also depends on your scale, ten printers or a thousand.